# Turning off ANSI colours for Laravel artisan command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, command-prompt

When i run any php artisan commands it always puts some that trailing characters[32m], [39m] and all those numbers. How am I gonna fix this ?

```
A:\xampp\htdocs\5.2>php artisan --version
[32mLaravel Framework[39m version [33m5.2.41[39m
```

Comment: Which terminal are you using? Since you are on windows, try using `git bash`.

Answer (score 7):

Those are ANSI colours - an attempt to make it look nicer, easier to read. If your terminal doesn't support ANSI, you can turn them off by passing a command-line parameter `--no-ansi`:

```
php artisan --version --no-ansi
```

Comment: Any idea why am I encountering this problem right after I have updated my laptop with the Windows 10 Anniversary Update while my other colleagues are not encountering this problem?

Comment: Do I always have to type --no ansi because it's just kinda tiring. I need permanent solution, Sir

Comment: @RHAMAB you can install something like ANSICON (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) to enable ANSI in your Windows terminal or you could make an alias so that --no-ansi is applied by default

Comment: Yeah I have Git Bash, I forgot that i could use it thanks everyone

Comment: ANSICON doesnt work for me, and @RHAMAB, powershell also displays ANSI color without any problem